# What can cause a sink's pivot rod connector to leak water?

Tags: water, leak, sink

**Background**: When running water in my bathroom sink, I'm seeing a small water leak (about a drop per minute). I traced the source to the bottom of the pivot rod connector - see the red circle in the attached picture.

**Questions:** Given that the leak doesn't appear to come from where the connector itself is screwed in, what might the cause be? Can water still be reaching the pivot rod itself?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **what might the cause be?**

- The connector isn't tight, so the pivot assembly is loose, so water can work past the seals.
- It was assembled with dirt in the seals
- A seal has failed or is damaged
- Something else.

> **Can water still be reaching the pivot rod itself?**

Yes.

---

I would disassemble, clean and inspect. replace any worn or damaged parts - especially rubber/plastic seals around or in the pivot assembly. Reassemble and test.

---

Example from Grohe:

[image]

```
8.4 45265 Nut and bushings
```

Comment: With those plastic rod nuts it is also common to see a hairline crack on the nut, barely visible, due to over tightening.

Comment: Also, I hope what I think I see is not indeed what I think; clear silicone caulk between the sink and the drain assembly nut. Nooooo....

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - what's the appropriate seal for this connector? Plumbers tape or something else?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - What's the concern re: clear silicone caulk?

Comment: @craig, there's two special tapered washers, one on each side of the pivot ball. You can buy replacement sets. You shouldn't normally need any tape or other sealant. Tighten until snug, take care not to over-tighten.

Comment: I meant the caulk used above, it will prevent normally required maintenance. The seal for a pop-up assembly is with plumber's putty on top (between the upper drain flange/trim ring and the sink) and a rubber gasket on the bottom (between the sink and the metal friction ring and hex nut). The silicone has provided you with an un-removable (un-repairable) drain assembly. Destruction and replacement will be your only avenue for future repair.

Comment: Turned out the issue was a cracked washer inside the pivot rod connector.

Answer (score 1):

I had a leak in the pivot arm that only showed up when a large amount of water went through at once (eg: plugging the drain, filling the sink, and then unplugging the drain).

The solution was that the beveled washer that sits inside the hole was sitting on top of debris and not mating with the surface properly. Had to pull the washer out and wipe the inside of the hole to get rid of rust and dirt.

I put it all back together with some dielectric grease (didn't have plumbers grease on hand) and everything is dry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the O-ring or bushing inside the nut providing sealing between the nut and the pivot rod was (suspected) damaged when installed, as the minor leak was there for a long time before I recognized the issue with water marks underneath the sink. Replacing this O-ring, also applying some white PTFE thread tape over the threads to ensure complete sealing, did fix the leak.